# Kivy keyboard_on_key_down working doesn't convert text on one of inputs

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having a little problem with my code - I have 5 TextInputs where I want to write letters whenever button is pressed I move to another window, it works fine as it is.
The problem lays whenever I am trying to write without capslock on, the 4 first letters will convert by `self.text=text.upper()` function, however the last one doesn't seem to work - it reads the letter twice - first the one that comes from function and then one letters as a lowercase, but I don't know from where it comes and how prevent my code from taking it.

```
import kivy
import sys
kivy.require('1.11.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import choice
import math
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import string 
from functools import partial
letters= string.ascii_lowercase
Builder.load_file("GuessWord.kv")

def set_color(letter, color):
    COLORS_DICT  = {"W" : "ffffff", "Y" : "ffff00", "G" : "00ff00"}
    c = COLORS_DICT.get(color, "W")
    return f"[color={c}]{letter}[/color]"

class MyTextInput(TextInput):   
    focused = 'id1'

    def change_focus(self, *args):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        if app.root is not None:
            # Now access the container.
            layout = app.root.ids["layout"]
            # Access the required widget and set its focus.
            print("Changefocus", MyTextInput.focused)
            layout.ids[MyTextInput.focused].focus = True

    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print(keycode,text)
        focusedid = int(MyTextInput.focused[2])


        if keycode[1] == "backspace":
            if self.text=="":
                if int(MyTextInput.focused[2]) > 1:
                    self.text = ""
                    focusedid -= 1
                    MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(focusedid)
            else:
                self.text = self.text[:-1]
        if keycode[1] == "right":
            if int(MyTextInput.focused[2]) < 5:
                focusedid += 1
                MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(focusedid)
            elif int(MyTextInput.focused[2]) == 5:
                MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(1)
                
        elif keycode[1] == "left":
            if int(MyTextInput.focused[2]) > 1:
                focusedid -= 1
                MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(focusedid)
            elif int(MyTextInput.focused[2]) == 1:
                MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(5)
        
        elif keycode[1] in letters:
            if int(MyTextInput.focused[2]) <= 5:
                self.text=text.upper()
                if int(MyTextInput.focused[2]) <5 :               
                    focusedid += 1
                    MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(focusedid)
                
            
        self.change_focus()
        print("After changing", MyTextInput.focused)
        return True
class MainScreen(Widget):
    pass                 
class TestingappApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()
    
TestingappApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
#:import threading threading
#:import partial functools.partial



<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: "vertical"             
        CustomBox:
            size_hint: 1,0.5
            id: layout
            cols:5

<CustomBox@BoxLayout>:
    MyTextInput:
        id: id1
        font_size: 120
        halign: "center"
        focus: True
        focused: "id1"
        multiline: False
    MyTextInput:
        id: id2
        font_size: 120
        halign: "center"
        focused: "id2"
        multiline: False
    MyTextInput:
        id: id3
        font_size: 120
        halign: "center"
        focused: "id3"
        multiline: False
    MyTextInput:
        id: id4
        font_size: 120
        halign: "center"
        focused: "id4"
        multiline: False
    MyTextInput:
        id: id5
        font_size: 120
        halign: "center"
        focused: "id5"
        multiline: False
```

Comment: I suggest to use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: maybe you run `upper` in wrong place and it doesn't convert last char or you append too many chars. Using `print()` you could check it. Frankly, to answer for this problem I would also use `print()` to observe how it works.

Comment: I tried that - it works properly all the way untill last TextInput and I don't know where it creates this extra letter

Comment: did you use `print()` in different places to see how values are changed?

Comment: I used it in different places of keyboard_on_key_down and the change_focus function, it is working good - just the last letter is being shown twice, first is from proper place, second is out of nowhere.

Comment: it has something to do with focus. If I add `else` in `if int(MyTextInput.focused[2]) <5 :` to move from last to first then it doesn't have problem. Maybe if object loose focus then it doesn't put new char at the end, but if it doesn't change focus them it add new char.

Comment: maybe it should run code on `key_up` instead of `key_down`. System may first run `key_down`, next update widget (if it still focused) and later `key_up` (so widget should have already all text and it would be simpler to remove it). OR you would search information to skip adding text when widget is still focused - maybe it would need to block access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that code is more complex:

- first it runs `keyboard_on_key_down()` which you use to add text in widget,
- next it checks focus and if focus is the same then it runs `input_text()` which is proper function to put/add text in widget and it adds second char,
- next it may also run `on_text()` which is executed when `self.text` was changed,
- and finally it runs `keyboard_on_key_up()`

So last widget doesn't change focus so it runs `insert_text()` which adds second char. But you can create empty function `insert_text()` to stop it. It will stop also numbers, etc.

```
    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        pass
```

but maybe all code should run in `insert_text()` instead of `keyboard_on_key_down()

---

See doc for Text Input:

- [usage-example](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#usage-example). There is `on_text()`, `on_enter()`, `on_focus()`.
- [filtering](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#filtering). There is `input_text()`

---

Full code (`.kv` is the same):

```
import kivy
import sys
kivy.require('1.11.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import choice
import math
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import string 
from functools import partial

letters = string.ascii_lowercase
Builder.load_file("GuessWord.kv")

def set_color(letter, color):
    COLORS_DICT  = {"W" : "ffffff", "Y" : "ffff00", "G" : "00ff00"}
    c = COLORS_DICT.get(color, "W")
    return f"[color={c}]{letter}[/color]"

class MyTextInput(TextInput):   
    focused = 'id1'

    def change_focus(self, *args):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        if app.root is not None:
            # Now access the container.
            layout = app.root.ids["layout"]
            # Access the required widget and set its focus.
            print("Changefocus", MyTextInput.focused)
            layout.ids[MyTextInput.focused].focus = True

    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        print('[insert_text] substring:', substring)
        print('[insert_text] self.text:', self.text)
        #substring = substring.upper()
        #return super().insert_text(substring, from_undo=from_undo)        

    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        print('[on_text]', instance, 'have:', value)

    def keyboard_on_key_up(self, window, keycode):
        print('[keyboard_on_key_up] keycode:', keycode)
        print('[keyboard_on_key_up] self.text:', self.text)
        print('---')

    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
    
        print('[keyboard_on_key_down] keycode:', keycode)
        print('[keyboard_on_key_down] text:', text)
        print('[keyboard_on_key_down] self.text:', self.text)
        
        focusedid = int(MyTextInput.focused[2])

        if keycode[1] == "backspace":
            if self.text == "":
                if focusedid > 1:
                    self.text = ""
                    focusedid -= 1
                    MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(focusedid)
            else:
                self.text = self.text[:-1]
                
        if keycode[1] == "right":
            if focusedid < 5:
                focusedid += 1
                MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(focusedid)
            elif focusedid == 5:
                MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(1)
                
        elif keycode[1] == "left":
            if focusedid > 1:
                focusedid -= 1
                MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(focusedid)
            elif int(MyTextInput.focused[2]) == 1:
                MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(5)
        
        elif keycode[1] in letters:
            if focusedid <= 5:
                self.text = text.upper()
                if focusedid < 5 :               
                    focusedid += 1
                    MyTextInput.focused = "id" + str(focusedid)
            
        self.change_focus()
        print("[keyboard_on_key_down] after changing focus:", MyTextInput.focused)
        return True
        
class MainScreen(Widget):
    pass        
         
class TestingappApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()
    
TestingappApp().run()
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for detailed explanation, I didn't understand the order of functions it was doing.

Comment: I met similar order in other GUIs - `key_down` before text is inserted to widget, `key_up` after text is inserted to widget, other functions I found in documentation. And when I added all of them with `print()` then I could see order. I wondered if there is TextInput which can get only one char, or which can use pattern i.e `....-..-..` to get only  dates ie.`2022-03-20`. It could make code simpler. (PL: powodzenia)